# Empty columns A and B deleted succesfully but C and D not moved to A and B only D is moved to A cell C values not shown in excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

This is my code

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')->setCellValue('C2', 'world!')->setCellValue('C3', 'Hello')->setCellValue('D1', 'test')->setCellValue('D2', 'world!')->setCellValue('D3', 'Hello');

$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn) - 1;$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
for($column = $highestColumn; $column >= 0; --$column) {
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column,$row);$err = $cell->getValue();
         if (!empty($err)) {
               break;
        } if (empty($err)) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('A');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('B');
        } } }

Comment: Don't edit your original question and change it to something completely different.... it makes any answers to the original question totally meaningless, and totally useless to anybody else using SO.... if you have to ask a new question, then ___ask a new question___ don't simply change your existing question

Answer (score 0):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->removeColumn('D');
```

to remove column `D`

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->removeColumn('D', 3);
```

to remove 3 consecutive columns beginning with column `D` (ie `D`-`F`)

But you'll need to write the logic yourself to identify whether a column is empty or not

**EDIT**

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
];
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->removeColumn('B');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('removeColumnTest.xlsx');
```

The above code works, and creates a spreadsheet containing:

```
   A  B
1  1  3
2  4  6
3  7  9
```

This is the expected result of removing a column.... Column B has been removed, and all subsequent columns (only C in this example) are shuffled back so that column C becomes the new column B.

**EDIT #2**

How to check the columns that are empty

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestDataColumn();
$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn) - 1;
$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestDataRow();
// Check columns in reverse order if you want to delete empty columns
//   because the removeColumn() has less work to do if we're deleting backwards
for($column = $highestColumn; $column >= 0; --$column) {
    // Loop through the rows in the current column
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
        // check the cell in each row
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column,$row);
        if (!empty($cell->getValue())) {
            // Don't bother checking any more cells in this column if a cell isn't empty
            // Just move on to the previous column
            break;
        }
        // column is empty, so do whatever you want here.... e.g. delete or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your infomation. But excel column not deleting

Comment: Then raise a bug report on github with a SSCCE to demonstrate the problem. This is the documented method for deleting a column from a spreadsheet using PHPExcel..... it works on my test systems (I've just checked it).... if you believe that it doesn't work, then you need to show me that it isn't working as well

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('D');

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('D');                                  column D not removed my excel

Comment: You're simply telling me that it doesn't work: I've run tests myself this morning to prove that it does work. Provide me with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks this is working fine, and also please tell me how to find the particullar column is empty

Comment: To identify if a column was empty or not, you'd need to loop through all the cells in that column and test them to see if they all matched your definition of empty

Comment: $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('A3', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('C2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C3', 'Hello');
            
   
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

Comment: This is my sample code how to find the empty columns in that code